# How to start script and put standard input in one command?

Tags: shell, input

I have a console program which uses standard input and output.

For example I call : `./program_name` and after that I enter input

I need to make this two actions in one command like: `./program_name 'my input string'` (this command returns `Abort trap: 6`).

How to do that?

I haven't source code for the program.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a here string

```
./program_name <<< 'my input string'
```

or a here document (longer, but standard):

```
./program_name <<EOF
my input string
EOF
```

Comment: This is the better answer, since it doesn't start an additional process like the pipeline does.

Answer (score 4):

```
echo my input string | ./program_name
```

Or, if you are a quotist:

```
echo "my input string" | ./program_name
```

Another handy tip is a subshell to collect output from multiple sources, for example:

```
( echo header; cat /etc/passwd; echo footer ) | ./program_name
```

Comment: I think it would be much more readable if you put `my input string` in quotes.